# SSRS Group Expression on a Column that may have a null value

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that I am doing dynamic grouping on that displays an agenda with time. grouping performed on a field called subheader and then the agenda times (another field)  displayed under that group subheader.

The problem that I am having is that I want to avoid the grouping if the parameter is null. I just want to sort by the time if there is nothing in the sub header group. Times are being displayed in the wrong order for the titles where the subheader field is null

Comment: Hiya Andy, dunno about others but I'm having a tough time visualising what you're trying to achieve. Could you update your post to include some sample data, and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your report, I can't tell how your grouping works.

If grouping the NULLs won't affect the report, you can use ISNOTHING to group the records with the NULL value together. Then sort by the same group field then your time field.

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(FIELDS!Subheader.Value), "", FIELDS!Subheader.Value)
```

But if you want them separate, **group by** a **unique ID** (if you have one in the data) or a **random number**  to keep the blanks separated:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(FIELDS!Subheader.Value), CEILING(RND()*100000), FIELDS!Subheader.Value)
```

Sort by the same IIF expression used in the Group By field then sort by Agenda_Time.